# Can't get controller reference in directive linkFn

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to porting the [angular-unit-converter](https://github.com/alexandernst/angular-unit-converter/blob/master/src/angular-unit-converter.js) directive to typescript in **angularjs@1.4.5**. However I cannot get angularjs to inject the controller for the `require` directive.

It throws

> Cannot read property '$parsers' of undefined

Because `ngModel` is `undefined`.

Here's my attempt

```
// typescript conversion of https://github.com/alexandernst/angular-unit-converter
import { Decimal } from "decimal.js";
import { IDirective, IDirectiveFactory, IDirectiveLinkFn, IScope, INgModelController, IAttributes, IAugmentedJQuery } from "angular";

interface IUnitConverterScope extends IScope {
    [key: string]: any;
    convertFrom;
    convertTo;
}

export class UnitConverterDirective implements IDirective<IUnitConverterScope> {
    public link;
    public restrict = "A";
    public require: "ngModel";
    public template = "";
    public scope = {
        convertFrom: "@",
        convertTo: "@"
    };

    constructor() {
        // It's important to add `link` to the prototype or you will end up with state issues.
        // See http://blog.aaronholmes.net/writing-angularjs-directives-as-typescript-classes/#comment-2111298002 for more information.
        this.link = this._link.bind(this);
    }

    public static Factory(): IDirectiveFactory<IUnitConverterScope> {
        const directive = (/*list of dependencies*/) => {
            return new UnitConverterDirective(/*list of dependencies*/);
        };

        directive["$inject"] = [];

        return directive;
    }

    private _link(scope: IUnitConverterScope, element: IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: IAttributes, ngModel: INgModelController) {
        console.log(ngModel);
        Decimal.config({
            precision: 10
        });

        const units = {
            // Size/distance
            "mm": 0.001,
            "cm": 0.01,
            "m": 1,
            "km": 1000,
            "in": 0.0254,
            "ft": 0.3048,
            "yd": 0.9144,
            "mi": 1609.344,

            // Weight
            "mg": 0.001,
            "g": 1,
            "kg": 1000,
            "oz": 28.3495231,
            "lb": 453.59237
        };

        scope.do_convertFrom = (value) => {
            if (!scope.convertFrom || scope.convertFrom === "") { return value; }

            let from = new Decimal(units[scope.convertFrom]);
            let to = new Decimal(units[scope.convertTo]);
            return (new Decimal(value).dividedBy(from.dividedBy(to))).toNumber();
        };

        scope.do_convertTo = (value) => {
            if (!scope.convertTo || scope.convertTo === "") { return value; }

            let from = new Decimal(units[scope.convertFrom]);
            let to = new Decimal(units[scope.convertTo]);
            return (new Decimal(value).times(from.dividedBy(to))).toNumber();
        };

        let p = (viewValue) => {
            let m = viewValue.match(/^\-?\d+((\.|\,)\d+)?$/g);
            if (m !== null) {
                return scope.do_convertFrom(parseFloat(viewValue));
            }
        };
        let f = (modelValue) => {
            return scope.do_convertTo(parseFloat(modelValue));
        };

        ngModel.$parsers.push(p);
        ngModel.$formatters.push(f);

        scope.$watch("[convertFrom, convertTo]", () => {
            ngModel.$modelValue = "";
        });
    }
}
```

You can see a live [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tywoxg?file=dir.ts) (open the console to see the error)

If I just write plain JS it works -> http://plnkr.co/edit/inuTNJ5OGhPHWmD09WWD?p=preview

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be noticed that such class design doesn't work well for directives in TS, a class just provides extra boilerplate but there are no obvious benefits. It could be just typed directive factory function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `require` is never defined. It should be

```
public require = "ngModel";
```

instead of

```
public require: "ngModel";
```

This sort of errors can be eliminated by enabling TypeScript `strictNullChecks` compiler option.

Comment: OH MY GOD! I can't believe I missed that :/